# If location access permission denied,than move camera to

Tags: android, google-maps, kotlin

I have this code below - which is basically google maps app, which on startup asks permission for location, and if accepted, then moves camera to the current location. I have tried many things, that just don't work - if a person declines permission to location, then move the camera to xwz coordinates..... . Now it just centers the whole map, and that's it. Please help! Thank you!

```
class MapsActivity : AppCompatActivity(), OnMapReadyCallback {

    private lateinit var mMap: GoogleMap

    private var latitude:Double=0.toDouble()
    private var longitude:Double=0.toDouble()

    private lateinit var mLastLocation: Location
    private var mMarker: Marker? = null

    //Location
    lateinit var fusedLocationProviderClient: FusedLocationProviderClient
    lateinit var locationRequest: LocationRequest
    lateinit var locationCallback: LocationCallback

    companion object{
        private const val MY_PERMISSION_CODE: Int = 1000
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps)
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        val mapFragment = supportFragmentManager
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)

        //Request runtime permission
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (checkLocationPermission()) {
                buildLocationRequest()
                buildLocationCallBack()

                fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
                fusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, locationCallback, Looper.myLooper())
            }
        }else {
            buildLocationRequest()
            buildLocationCallBack()

            fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
            fusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, locationCallback, Looper.myLooper())
        }
    }

    private fun buildLocationCallBack() {
        locationCallback = object : LocationCallback(){
            override fun onLocationResult(p0: LocationResult?) {
                mLastLocation = p0!!.locations.get(p0!!.locations.size-1) //Get last location

                if(mMarker != null){
                    mMarker!!.remove()
                }

                latitude = mLastLocation.latitude
                longitude = mLastLocation.longitude

                val latLng = LatLng(latitude,longitude)
                val markerOptions = MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("Your position").icon(bitmapDescriptorFromVector(this@MapsActivity, R.drawable.m1))
                mMarker = mMap!!.addMarker(markerOptions)

                //Move camera
                mMap!!.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng))
                mMap!!.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11f))
            }
        }
    }

    private fun buildLocationRequest() {
        locationRequest = LocationRequest()
        locationRequest.priority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY
        locationRequest.interval = 5000
        locationRequest.fastestInterval = 3000
        locationRequest.smallestDisplacement = 10f
    }

    private fun checkLocationPermission() : Boolean {

        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            if(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION))
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(
                    android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
                ), MY_PERMISSION_CODE)
            else
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(
                    android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
                ), MY_PERMISSION_CODE)
            return false
        }
        else
            return true
    }

    //Override OnRequestPermissionResult

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
        when (requestCode) {
            MY_PERMISSION_CODE -> {
                if(grantResults.size > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                        if (checkLocationPermission()) {
                            buildLocationRequest()
                            buildLocationCallBack()

                            fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
                            fusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, locationCallback, Looper.myLooper())

                            mMap!!.isMyLocationEnabled=true

                        }
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        fusedLocationProviderClient.removeLocationUpdates(locationCallback)
        super.onStop()
    }

    override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap

        //Init google Play Services
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                mMap!!.isMyLocationEnabled = true
            }
        }
        else
            mMap!!.isMyLocationEnabled = true


        //Enable Zoom control
        mMap.uiSettings.isZoomControlsEnabled=true

        //map style

        try {

            val success = googleMap.setMapStyle(
                MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(this, R.raw.style_json))
        } catch (e: Resources.NotFoundException) {
            Log.e("MapsActivity", "Can't find style. Error: ", e)
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Why movecamera and animatecamera both are used ?

Comment: To zoom to 11f.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you made mistake in `onLocationResult`.

You are using `moveCamera` and `animateCamera` at same time.

Instead you can use `newLatLngZoom`. Like,

```
mMap!!.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng , 11f))
```